# Characters in URL after host transmitted as-is?

Tags: http

If I visit the URL:

```
http://foo/bar
```

Than the web browser will connect to host `foo` by TCP on port 80 and transmit a GET request:

```
GET /bar HTTP...
```

Clearly not all characters in the `bar` part will work (be transmitted verbatim).  For example the space character (#20).

Of the 256 possible bytes, which will a standard web browser transmit verbatim (as is, without special encoding) from a URL entered into the address bar to the GET request, and which will it not?

Comment: URLs are no longer limited to ASCII. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC-3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) talks about reserved and unreserved characters. Unreserved characters can be used without special encoding; everything else must be url encoded, using the %xx notation.

The unreserved characters include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.

The browser is smart enough to automatically escape space and other characters before opening a socket connection to the server.

EDIT

Reserved characters need not be encoded when used for their intended purpose. But, when they are used as part of query string or path components, they must be url-encoded.

The reserved characters are `!  *   '   (   )   ;   :   @   &   =   +   $   ,   /   ?   #   [   ]`

For example, here is a url

`http://example.com:8090/email/tigerwoods%40gmail.com?folder=sport%2Fgolf`

Over here, the `/` and `?` are not encoded when they serve their normal roles. However, the `@` symbol is encoded as part of the email. The `/` is also encoded as part of the query string parameter.

Comment: Your list is not exhaustive.  For example at least `?#&` are transmitted as is.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling See my updates. `?#&` are reserved characters. They require encoding when used within the path, query string or fragment identifier portions of the url. But when they are used for their intended purposes, they mustn't be encoded.